# How to stop running timeout jquery function on click and run new function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I'm trying to update a view with ajax call in every 5 seconds. I've done it in the following way.

```
function getData(a, b, c) {
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'url',
        success : function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            setTimeout(getData, 5000, a, b, c);
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData(1, 2, 3);       
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
    getData(4,5,6);
});
```

But, in this way as many functions are running as many click.

I need to stop the previous one and run new one or change the parameter of running function.

Comment: use  `clearTimeout()` to stop execution of your setTimeOut function..

Comment: I've tried this but can't catch the running event. clearTimeout(???)

Comment: You can set on more parameter in  ajax call. `async : false`. It will make each call one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ajax `abort()` function to stop the request when button is clicked and start a new one...

Here i have an example for you, that how abort works... take a look at code and try this...

```
<script>

var prev_request = false;
var xhr;
var myTimeoutReq;
//var myCondition = true,

function getData(a, b,c,myCondition ) 
{
    if(prev_request == true)
    {
        xhr.abort();
    }

    xhr =  $.ajax({
                url     : 'url',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                    prev_request = true;
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                    if(myCondition == true)
                    {
                        myTimeoutReq = setTimeout(getData, 5000, a, b, c,true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        clearTimeout(myTimeoutReq);
                    }   
                },
                complete: function( xhr ) {
                    prev_request = false;
                }
            });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getData(1, 2, 3, true);       
});

$('.btn').click(function(){
    getData(4,5,6,false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't know why, but prev_request always remaining false and that's why getData(1,2,3), getData(4,5,6), .... all are running

Comment: your ajax is aborted only, if your previous request is running...because on complete of ajax we have set prev_request to fasle, prev_request will only be true when first request is running...

Comment: It keeps ajax requesting in every 5 seconds. I need to completely abort the previous request on button click.

Comment: when you  click on btn then ajax `getData(4,5,6)` runs and in callback again getData(a,b,c), then which request will be sent ?? `getData(4,5,6)` or `getData(1,2,3)`

Comment: getData(4, 5, 6) only, if I clicked getData(7,8,9) again then getData(7,8,9) only

Comment: okay okay i got it, you want to stop setTimeout function when getData(4,5,6) runs ???.. wait a minute

Comment: @user1710782, check out this code now... your ajax will be stoped after running only once for `getData(4,5,6)` when you click btn...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110466/discussion-between-manjeet-barnala-and-user1710782).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) to finish previous timeout for that you need to assign the `setTimeout` returned object first. Declare a global object to assign timeout object to that it could be assessed through other functions.

*Assigning the timeout object*

```
someGlobalTimeoutObject = setTimeout(getData, 5000, a, b, c);
```

*Clearing timeout object*

```
clearTimeout(someGlobalTimeoutObject);
```

Comment: var myObj = setTimeout(getData, 5000, a, b, c);
I'm using this, but in click function console.log(myObj) saying myObj is undefined

Comment: Defined it outside getData to make it global then you would be able to access in other functions. Once you defined it globally do not use var inside getData as it be a new local object.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getData(a, b, c) {
    if(detData.ajax) {
        detData.ajax.abort();
        clearTimeout(getData);
    }
    detData.ajax = $.ajax({
        url     : 'url',
        success : function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
            setTimeout(getData, 5000, a, b, c);
        }
    });
}
```